# how can i unserialize Symfony transport messages?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I want unserilize the Symfony messages in the table messenger_messages.

I tried with unserialize() function but I've got a notice saying: "unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1380 bytes in ..." (message cut).

I had as result only the notice and not the unserilized string I passed to the function.

Here an example I tried to unserialize (I changed some data for privacy):

```
O:36:\"Symfony\\Component\\Messenger\\Envelope\":2:{s:44:\"\0Symfony\\Component\\Messenger\\Envelope\0stamps\";a:1:{s:46:\"Symfony\\Component\\Messenger\\Stamp\\BusNameStamp\";a:1:{i:0;O:46:\"Symfony\\Component\\Messenger\\Stamp\\BusNameStamp\":1:{s:55:\"\0Symfony\\Component\\Messenger\\Stamp\\BusNameStamp\0busName\";s:26:\"messenger.bus.pimcore-core\";}}}s:45:\"\0Symfony\\Component\\Messenger\\Envelope\0message\";O:36:\"App\\Hubspot\\TransactionalMailMessage\":1:{s:45:\"\0App\\Hubspot\\TransactionalMailMessage\0payload\";a:4:{s:7:\"emailId\";i:53540933612;s:9:\"recipient\";a:7:{s:5:\"email\";s:23:\"lorenzo.sequi@gmail.com\";s:5:\"phone\";s:10:\"3289736434\";s:9:\"firstName\";s:5:\"Sequi\";s:8:\"lastName\";s:7:\"Lorenzo\";s:12:\"customerType\";s:7:\"privato\";s:17:\"newsletterConsent\";b:1;s:5:\"admin\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";a:13:{s:11:\"ID_ANNUNCIO\";i:5920;s:14:\"TOKEN_ANNUNCIO\";s:15:\"PR65E095202E52F\";s:15:\"TITOLO_ANNUNCIO\";s:41:\"Agazzini ENDURO CARBON CANE CREEK EDITION\";s:12:\"EMAIL_AUTORE\";s:23:\"lorenzo.sequi@gmail.com\";s:15:\"TELEFONO_AUTORE\";s:10:\"3289736434\";s:12:\"URL_ANNUNCIO\";s:39:\"http://localhost/announcement/5920/view\";s:17:\"URL_ANNUNCIO_EDIT\";s:39:\"http://localhost/announcement/5920/edit\";s:18:\"URL_ANNUNCIO_ADMIN\";s:65:\"https://www.ebikemood.com/admin/login/deeplink?object_5920_object\";s:6:\"STATUS\";s:6:\"review\";s:15:\"NOTE_UNAPPROVED\";s:0:\"\";s:13:\"NOTE_REJECTED\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"OFFER_PRICE\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"OFFER_DESCRIPTION\";s:0:\"\";}s:6:\"sendId\";N;}}}
```

Comment: That certainly _looks_ like PHP serialize/unserialize format. Maybe you could look in [the source of the Symfony Messenger component](https://github.com/symfony/messenger) and see if you can find where the default serialzation / unserialization is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

First, check which serializer is used in your config, e.g.

```
framework:
    messenger:
        serializer: ??? # <- HERE
```

If not explicitly set, messenger component uses its default internal Serializer:

[Symfony\Component\Messenger\Transport\Serialization\Serializer](https://github.com/symfony/messenger/blob/7.0/Transport/Serialization/Serializer.php)

Now, the tricky part is that it expects an encoded envelope of a specific format:

```
[
    'body' => '',
    'headers' => ['type' => '', 'X-Message-Stamp-A' => '', 'X-Message-Stamp-B' => '', ...],
]
```

If you don't use any additional metadata (like stamps, etc.), you can now simply inject Serializer and try to create the envelope manually and decode the message:

```
$result = $this->serializer->decode([
    'body' => 'yourSerializedMessageString',
    'headers' => ['type' => \get_class(YourMessageObject)],
]);
```

Otherwise, you'll need to populate 'headers' element with all headers from the message (if you can obtain from wherever you have it bypassing the messenger component).